# TestNG + Mockito + PowerMock - verifyStatic() does not work

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, testng, powermock

I am new TestNG and unit-testing in general. I am using TestNG 6.9.6 with Mockito 1.10.19 and PowerMock 1.6.4. I want to verify whether the `myMethod()` method in `MyService` class internally calls the static method `Util.myStaticMethod` with the correct arguments. Since verification of static methods is not natively supported in Mockito, I am using PowerMock along with it. My Test class is shown below:

```
public class MyTest
{
    private MyService myService;

    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> argCaptor;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
        myService = new MyService();
    }

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(MyService.class)
    public void myTest()
    {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Util.class);
        myService.myMethod("arg");

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(10);
        Util.myStaticMethod(anyString());
    }
}
```

This test is expected to fail, as `myMethod` calls the static method `Util.myStaticMethod()` only once. But when i run the test, it always passes, no matter what value i pass to `PowerMockito.verifyStatic()`.

Also, if I write another test method in this class and then run the test, I get the following error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at mypackage.MyTest.myTest(MyTest.java:21)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

    at mypackage.MyTest.myTest.setup(MyTest.java:10)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  MyTest.setup:10 UnfinishedVerification 
Missing method call for ver...

Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
```

It fails at the `verifyStatic()` method, which makes me think that the verifyStatic() method needs something more that i am not providing. Also, it indicates the total number of tests as 3 whereas in this case I have only two test methods.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :** As suggested, I tried putting `MyUtil` class in the the `@PrepareForTest` annotation, it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I think this is very specific to TestNG configurations, since all of the JUnit examples work 'out of the box'!

Read through [this](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage) link from the PowerMock GitHub site which describes further detail on how to use TestNG together with PowerMock.  Exactly your scenario of verifying calls to mocked `static` methods is described there using this example code:

> ```
> @PrepareForTest(IdGenerator.class)
> public class MyTestClass {
>
>    @Test
>    public void demoStaticMethodMocking() throws Exception {
>       mockStatic(IdGenerator.class);
>       when(IdGenerator.generateNewId()).thenReturn(2L);       
>       new ClassUnderTest().methodToTest();
>
>       // Optionally verify that the static method was actually called
>       verifyStatic();
>       IdGenerator.generateNewId();
>    }
>
> }
> ```

Which is then followed by this nugget of information:

> For this to work you need to tell TestNG to use the PowerMock object factory

This is done using either TestNG XML config, or in the test's code itself. For completeness I've copied below the options given at the above URL. FWIW I extended `PowerMockTestCase` and the verification worked as you expect.

Finally, don't forget to `@PrepareForTest` the correct class - i.e. the class containing the `static` methods which you want to mock, as @Bax pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35801671/993262).

As a further hint (which you probably already know about, but worth mentioning here anyway) since you aren't using Mockito to mock objects, `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` can be safely deleted.

Once you've got all this working, you might also like to consider whether the use of ['Black Magic'](http://martinfowler.com/articles/modernMockingTools.html) tools like Powermock is actually exposing [code smells](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CodeSmell.html) in your design?  Especially since it looks like the classes containing `static` methods are under your ownership.  This means you could use an alternative design that doesn't use `static`s.  I highly recommend Michael Feathers' book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44919.Working_Effectively_with_Legacy_Code), it might just change your whole approach to software design and testing...

Good luck!

> ## Configure TestNG to use the PowerMock object factory
>
> ### Using suite.xml
>
> In your suite.xml add the following in the suite tag: 
>   `object-factory="org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory"` e.g.
>
> ```
> <suite name="dgf" verbose="10"
>     object-factory="org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory">
>     <test name="dgf">
>         <classes>
>             <class name="com.mycompany.Test1"/>
>             <class name="com.mycompany.Test2"/>
>         </classes>
>     </test>
> ```
>
> If you're using Maven you may need to point out the file to Surefire:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>     <configuration>
>         <suiteXmlFiles>
>         <suiteXmlFile>suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
>         </suiteXmlFiles>
>     </configuration> 
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> ### Programmatically
>
> Add a method like this to your test class:
>
> ```
> @ObjectFactory public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
>      return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory(); 
> }
> ```
>
> or to be on the safe side you can also extend from the `PowerMockTestCase`:
>
> ```
> @PrepareForTest(IdGenerator.class) 
> public class MyTestClass extends PowerMockTestCase { ... }
> ```

Comment: My bad. I skipped the xml configuration part since I though surefire would take care of it. This resolved the issue. Will also look into improving the design, it is a legacy code indeed! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: This answer was very helpful in 2020!  Today, I confirm using TestNG 7.1.0, Mockito 3.6.28, PowerMock 2.0.9: It is *only* necessary to `extends PowerMockTestCase`.  I did not need `getObjectFactory`.

Answer (score 2):

Since this page is highly ranked in search results, I just wanted to add a few more things to the helpful documentation Stephen already wrote about. I just successfully migrated a JUnit test case to TestNG, after initially encountering some issues. I found that you can either do the suite.xml mods, or do it "programmatically", but it's not necessary to do both.

For doing it programmatically, the `@ObjectFactory` method did not work me, but subclassing `PowerMockTestCase` did. Here is my sample code:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@PrepareForTest(Pokeball.class)
public class PokeballTestTestNG extends PowerMockTestCase {
// Did not work for me
// @ObjectFactory
//    public IObjectFactory getObjectFactory() {
//        return new org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory();
//    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(Pokeball.class);

        Pokeball.getNetworkMessage();
        Pokeball.getNetworkMessageLang(42);
        Pokeball.getNetworkMessageLang(42);

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); //verify one time invocation (default), passes
//        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(11)); //fails
        Pokeball.getNetworkMessage(); //need to call the method per PowerMock operation - actual test is done here - Exception thrown here upon failure

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(2));
        Pokeball.getNetworkMessageLang(42);
    }
}
```

EDIT: the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myG</groupId>
    <artifactId>myTestDouble</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <powermock.version>1.7.0</powermock.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUnit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUnit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--TestNG-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Both TestNG & JUnit-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please tell what are maven dependencies you added for PowerMockito to work properly? I am getting the errors for the following class:

    import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;

Comment: @saint1729 I've added the pom.xml. You might not need every dependency on there, I'd imagine.