# Powermock static final method in final class

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

The Test case I am writing for:

```
public class AClassUnderTest {

    // This test class has a method call
    public Long methodUnderTest() {

         // Uses the FinalUtilityClass which contains static final method
         FinalUtilityClass.myStaticFinalMethod(<3-parameters-here>);

         // I want to mock above call so that test case for my "methodUnderTest" passes
    }
}
```

I have one final class.

```
public final class FinalUtilityClass {

   /**
    * Method has 3 parameters
    */
   public static final MyBean myStaticFinalMethod(<3-parameters-here>) {

   }
}
```

I have already added below code in my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FinalUtilityClass.class })
```

I want to write test case for mocking it.
I want to mock the call of `myStaticFinalMethod()` so that I can get the expected `MyBean` instatnce which I can use in further code to pass my test case.

The `<3-parameters-here>` are Calendar, String, String.

***I tried doing***:

**1)**

```
PowerMockito.mock(FinalUtilityClass.class)
PowerMockito.when(FinalUtilityClass.myStaticFinalMethod(<3-parameters-here>).thenReturn(new MyBean());
```

**2)**

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(FinalUtilityClass.class)
PowerMockito.when(FinalUtilityClass.myStaticFinalMethod(<3-parameters-here>).thenReturn(new MyBean());
```

**3)**

```
PowerMockito.spy(FinalUtilityClass.class)
PowerMockito.when(FinalUtilityClass.myStaticFinalMethod(<3-parameters-here>).thenReturn(new MyBean());
```

But nothing worked for me. Please suggest what is correct way for mocking `static final` method in `final` class.

Comment: Did you add `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` as a class level annotation in the test class?

Comment: definitely, my other cases are working well.

Comment: `PowerMockito` or `PowerMock` ?

Comment: its `PowerMockito`

Comment: Ok, sorry, Prepaturely answered then, I'll delete my answer. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: no worries, thanks for comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG + Mockito + PowerMock - verifyStatic() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801550/testng-mockito-powermock-verifystatic-does-not-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583202/powermockito-mock-single-static-method-and-return-object

Answer (score 9):

The following [steps](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic) are required to mock calls to static methods:

- Use the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` annotation at the class-level of the test case.
- Use the `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` annotation at the class-level of the test case
- Use `PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class)` to mock all methods of this class

When you follow these steps as documented, your tests should work. And as the OP seems to be confused about PowerMock vs. PowerMockito - that is (more or less) the same thing:

PowerMock and PowerMockito are based on the **same** technology. They just have different "connectors" to either work with EasyMock or Mockito. So, yes the above example says `PowerMock.mockStatic()` - but [PowerMockito](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.2/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#mockStatic-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class...-) has `mockStatic()` methods as well. In that sense: the *core* things (for example regarding **preparation** with annotations) are the same. See [here](http://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-powermock) for example (they are so close that the linked tutorial says "Intro to PowerMock" - although it does introduce PowerMockito.

And as you seem to not believe me - see this example:

```
package ghostcat.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

final class ClassWithStatic {
    public final static int ignoreMethodCall(String a, String b, int c) {
        System.out.println("SHOULD NOT SHOW UP: " + a);
        return c;
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassWithStatic.class)
public class MockStaticTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStatic.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ClassWithStatic.ignoreMethodCall("a", "b", 5)).thenReturn(42);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(ClassWithStatic.ignoreMethodCall("a", "b", 5), 42);
    }
}
```

This test passes; and doesn't print anything. Therefore the final static method gets mocked.

Comment: for static method it works well, but how about static final ?

Comment: According to the documentation: > Note that you can mock static methods in a class even though the class is final. The method can also be final

Comment: As per point **2)**, I tried with `mockStatic` but it dosen't mock the final method. It goes inside the method, which I want to mock. This works well with `static` methods, which are not final.

Comment: This answer uses `PowerMock` and the one which is used in the question is `PowerMockito`.

Comment: I agree with your example, what if in case `ClassWithStatic` is final ? My issue lies at that point in case of final class.

Comment: Wondering how much more time I have to spent here ... well, my own fault. I just updated the example and made the class final, too. And it still works. You see: all of that **does not** matter. Because what PowerMock(ito) is doing: it **changes** the byte code of the 
classes marked with @PrepareForTest . In other words: the **production** source code doesn't matter - because PowerMock will do its dark magic and simply create **different** byte code for that class at runtime. And seriously: have you tried taking my example (it is **complete**, just copy) and work with that?

Comment: sure, will try this example in my class.

Comment: It only works with Junit 4 but not Junit 5.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and it cost me a lot of time.

I solved it, based on this [Mock system class with PowerMock documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mock-System), when I realized that the `@PrepareForTest({ SomeClassToBePreparedForTesting.class })` must receive the class that calls the static methods defined in the final class, so the preparation for the test, in your case, must receive the `AClassUnderTest.class`.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ AClassUnderTest.class })
```

The correct way to mock the final class with the target static method is to use the `PowerMock.mockStatic(FinalClassThatDefinesStaticMethod.class)`, in your case the `FinalUtilityClass.class`.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(FinalUtilityClass.class)
PowerMockito.when(FinalUtilityClass.method(params)).thenReturn(return);
```

In addition, if you have some issue like: 'It's not possible to mock final methods', you can create the file `org/powermock/extensions/configuration.properties` and set this config `mockito.mock-maker-class=mock-maker-inline` like the [PowerMockito documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#mockito-mock-maker-inline) presents.