# TestNG + Mockito + PowerMock Always show "ClassNotPreparedException"

Tags: java, mockito, testng, powermock, powermockito

I use the Testng & Mockito & Powermock (Without Using Junit 3 or 4)to test my class `JeebiesKwCheckUtil` which contain static and final, I have do the code and pom as the Powermock intro but it still doesn't work at all , alway show the  `org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException`, it has drove me mad...

Code :
I write it just as the Powermock&mockito Intro. [Link](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method) is here;

```
@PrepareForTest(JeebiesKwCheckUtil.class)
public class JeebiesKwCheckUtilTest {
   @Test
   public void testMethodA() {
       PowerMockito.mockStatic(JeebiesKwCheckUtil.class); // Exception here
       // MethodA use stticMethodB
       Mockito.when(JeebiesKwCheckUtil.staticMethodB).thenReturn(Result);
       Assert.assertEquals(JeebiesKwCheckUtil.MethodA......)
   }
}
```

Pom File:
There is 4 Maven Jar here  Powermock's Version is 1.7.1

- the first two is PowerMock's -> [Mockito-2-Maven](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven#testng)
- the third is Testng (Version 6.13.1 > 6.9.10 )-> [Testng-Version-Require](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/TestNG)
- the forth is Mockito (Version 2.8.9) -> [Mockito-Version-Require](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions)

---

```
<properties>
    <powermock.version>1.7.1</powermock.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-testng</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
      <version>${powermock.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.13.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error:

```
org.powermock.api.mockito.ClassNotPreparedException: 
[Ljava.lang.Object;@29df4d43
The class com.yidian.serving.util.JeebiesKwCheckUtil not prepared for test.
at org.powermock.api.mockito.expectation.reporter.MockitoPowerMockReporter.classNotPrepared(MockitoPowerMockReporter.java:32)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockTypeValidatorFactory$DefaultMockTypeValidator.validate(MockTypeValidatorFactory.java:38)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.AbstractMockCreator.validateType(AbstractMockCreator.java:10)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:56)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:46)
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:73)
at com.yidian.serving.util.JeebiesKwCheckUtilTest.testCheckSensitiveWord(JeebiesKwCheckUtilTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:571)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Can anyone could give me a solution or adivse? Thanks Very Very much~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG + Mockito + PowerMock - verifyStatic() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801550/testng-mockito-powermock-verifystatic-does-not-work)

Answer (score 2):

I've get it done by my friend's help,

Extend `PowerMockTestCase` to Inject a 'Runner' just as Junit(PowerMockRunner...)

```
@PrepareForTest(JeebiesKwCheckUtil.class)
public class JeebiesKwCheckUtilTest extends PowerMockTestCase{...}
```

Ps. If you have meet a "SSL" Problem just as I then, Add a @..Ignore before class

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")
```

This problem is Truly Same as [TestNG + Mockito + PowerMock - verifyStatic() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801550/testng-mockito-powermock-verifystatic-does-not-work), but I also encounter the SSL problem which messed all the thing...