# PowerMock and Mockito UnfinishedVerificationException

Tags: java, mockito, testng, powermock, powermockito

I am having difficulties getting PowerMock and Mockito to work.

I am using these versions. They should be [compatible](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#supported-versions).

- powermock-core v 1.7.4
- powermock-api-mockito v 1.7.4
- powermock-module-junit4 v 1.7.4
- mockito-all v 1.10.19

I am also using TestNG, but I do not believe this has any affect on the outcome of this test.

I want to mock an object, call a method on the mocked object, and verify that a private method was called once within the mocked objects method.

I have constructed an example, that hopefully explains what I want to accomplish.

```
public class MyClass {

    public void execute(Object o) {
        valid(o);
    }

    private boolean valid(Object o) {
        return o != null;
    }
}
```

This is my test class

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class TestClass {
    @After
    public void validate() {
        validateMockitoUsage();
    }

    @Test
    public void executeTest() throws Exception {
        //Initialize the Class and create the spy
        MyClass myClass = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());

        //Execute the method which I wish to test
        myClass.execute(null);

        //I want to verify that the private valid method was called once.
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(myClass, times(1)).invoke("valid", anyObject());
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at TestClass.executeTest(MyClass.java:14)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: 

final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.


at TestClass.validate(MyClass.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

I have tried to search, but I could not find a solution for my problem. I believe this is a common error, and I am using PowerMock/Mockito wrong.

Comment: The first thing I see is that you should probably should be preparing `MyClass` instead of `TestClass`. See if that helps?

Comment: Well spotted. This is unfortunately just a typo when I wrote the SO question. I have fixed the typo.

Comment: The error message specifically states `Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: 

final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.`

Comment: Also given that you pass `null` try using that i.e: `.invoke("valid", null);`

Comment: Yes, that is true. So how do I avoid this error? I want to verify that the private method is called once with PowerMock.

Comment: `.invoke("valid", null);` does not change anything. I am using * anyObject()* because the argument could be anything.

Comment: Have a look at this example https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#a-full-example-of-partial-mocking-of-a-private-method

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. When I run it, it works fine. I just had to change the matcher slightly.

Comment: Try changing `anyObject()` to `any()` in your verify statement

Comment: anyObject() to any() did not help.

Comment: I found the issue after you reported back that you could not reproduce this issue. The issue is afterall TestNG. Everything works perfectly when I use junit4. Thank you all for suggestions.

Comment: Well that's good news! I was very confused because it worked fine for me on Junit haha

Comment: It is often the small things ;) Reporting back that you cannot reproduce a problem is often the solution. You can create an answer with your comment and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using TestNG to run your test, the @RunWith annotation is ignored as it is specific to JUnit.

To make this work, you have 2 options:

1. Run your test with JUnit.
2. OR Configure TestNG so that it uses PowerMock object factory. The configuration details are pretty well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35801550/testng-mockito-powermock-verifystatic-does-not-work).

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to replicate the issue myself on junit4. It turns out that it was an issue with TestNG.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added both these annotations when using powermock for testing private methods:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(<Class_containing_pvt_method>.class)
```

**@RunWith** annotation initializes powermock as runner for junit

**@PrepareForTest** annotation is used when mocking final classes, classes with final, private, static or native methods so that powermock can read from byte-code of these classes (because java do no allows reflection for private methods).